# Nao consigo centralizar o texto - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-centering

Preciso centralizar o texto do header, ja tentei varias formas e nao funciona. Alguem sabe onde esta o erro??

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  min-height: 9px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #383c38;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Login-Helper</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Se quer usar flex para centralizar na horizontal, no seu exemplo use `justify-content: center`, não `align-items`.

Answer (score 2):

O texto do `header` está dentro de uma tag `H1`, que não ocupa todo o tamanho do `header`, se adicionar a ela um `width: 100%` vai funcionar simplesmente usando em conjunto um `text-align: center`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  min-height: 9px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #383c38;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Login-Helper</h1>
</header>
```

Uma outra forma em precisar usar o `width: 100%` é usando `margin: 0 auto` (pode ver mais sobre `margin` aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  min-height: 9px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #383c38;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Login-Helper</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Tentei as duas sugestões e nao funciona. Algo de errado no meu vs code, so pode.. rs

Comment: o vs code é só um editor, precisa salvar e abrir no browser para testar que é onde fica rederizado corretamente. De qualquer forma tem ai dois exemplos funcionando, verifique se no navegador não certo